# Mathjax alignment in Shiny

Tags: html, css, shiny, mathjax

I've found ways to left-align ALL of the Mathjax equations in my shiny app, but I want to center a couple of equations. Is there a way to differentially apply this CSS?

```
tags$style(HTML("div.MathJax_Display{text-align: left !important;}"))),
```

Is there a way to specify "text-align: center" when I send the equation to output?

```
withMathJax(tags$p(equation))
```

Comment: As a temporary fix, I accidentally found that lines using \tag*{...} are centered anyway. I added a few blank tags for now, but a cleaner solution would be nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS classes as follows:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  withMathJax(),
  tags$style(HTML(
    "p.mjleft div.MathJax_Display{text-align: left !important;}",
    "p.mjcenter div.MathJax_Display{text-align: center !important;}"
  )),
  br(),
  tags$p("$$\\int_0^1$$", class = "mjleft"),
  tags$p("$$\\int_0^1$$", class = "mjcenter")
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]